# Reference equality for container objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

For a specific application we are storing id's of objects in specific classes. For example, a "product" object would have it's string id stored in a "ProductId" object. Likewise a "user" object would have it's string id stored in a UserId object (see example code below).

```
class Product {
  id: ProductId;
  price: number;
  ...
}

class User {
  id: UserId;
  name: string;
  ...

  constructor(id: UserId, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    ...
  }

}

class ProductId {
  id: string;

  constructor(id: string) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

class UserId {
  id: string;

  constructor(id: string) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

One issue with this approach is that storing objects in a Map and then trying to retrieve them (see below code) does not work because two UserId's with the same underlying id do not compare equal with ===.

```
const users = new Map<UserId, User>();

const user = new User(new UserId('8753098'), 'John'); 
users.set(user.id, user);

console.log(users.get(new UserId('8753098')); //undefined
```

It seems that javascript does not have operator overloading, or has no way of overriding the equality function.

I have also thought of working with a global map, and create Id's with a static method :

```
class UserId {

  private id: string;

  constructor(id: string) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  static userIds = new Map<string, UserId>();    

  static fromString(id: string) {
    let userId = userIds.get(id);
    if (userId === undefined) {
      userId = new UserId(id);
      userIds.set(id, userId);
    }
    return userId;
  }
}
```

But that has a potential memory leak because all objects are retained in the map and never released.

Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this fits your purpose but can also have to `toString()` in `UserId` class.

Then you can get/set by `users.set(user.id.toString(), user);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Instead of `class UserId` just do a type `type UserId = string`.

## More

If you are concerned about structural equality and would prefer nominal typing you can add a brand using an enum [as shown here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html)

```
enum UserIdBrand {}
type UserId = UserIdBrand & string;
```

Comment: Very interesting article